# Google Apps Script running twice

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a google apps script which is fired by a html page.

however it fire twice for some reason.

I tried to figure out the problem but cant find any.

Mentioned below are my codes:-

html:-

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue-grey darken-3" onclick="dostuffLeavenew()">Submit</a>


<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Thank You!!</h4>
      <p>Record has been Updated.</p><p>Please click close to continue.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=indileave" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons right">close</i>Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Client side code:-

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    
    const options = { format:'m/d/yyyy', yearRange:80};
    var delems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker-test');
    var dinstances = M.Datepicker.init(delems,options);
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getempatd).empatd();
  });
   
   function dostuffLeavenew()
  {
   var arrx = document.getElementById("cp").value;
   var dataArray = arrx.split(",")
   var array = [];
        for(i=0; i<dataArray.length; ++i){
        
        if(document.getElementById("A-"+dataArray[i]).checked == true)
        {
           var ele = document.getElementById("A-"+dataArray[i]).value;
           ele = ele.split(",");
           ele.push("Approved")
           ele = ele.flat();
           array.push(ele)
           
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("D-"+dataArray[i]).checked == true)
        {
           var ele = document.getElementById("D-"+dataArray[i]).value;
           ele = ele.split(",");
           ele = ele.flat();
           ele.push("Disapproved")
           array.push(ele)
           
        }
        
        }
            google.script.run.indiaddrecord(array)
            var singleModalElem = document.getElementById('modal1');
            var instance = M.Modal.getInstance(singleModalElem);
            instance.open();
  
  }
```

I have added the modal in my code. This code simply reload my page and this may be causing the problem because when I remove this line of code the script does not fire twice. Now the point is when you look at the `eventListener` it does not fire the `function dostuffLeavenew`. So what can be the reason?

Comment: Need [mcve]......

Comment: Which function is running twice? `empatd` or `indiaddrecord`? Also have you tried to add a `console.log` before the lines with `google.script.run` to see if you are calling twice or it's calling it twice internally?

Comment: `dostuffLeavenew()` is calling twice.

Comment: @Captain_D Do you mean that `dostuffLeavenew()` is called twice or that `dostuffLeavenew` calls `google.script.run` twice? If the project doesn't have any personal information and you think it's ok, could you share a copy of the project? It might be easier of I look into it directly. Also, remove the `document.addEventListener` part; it's not part of the problem and just adds noise :) And if you can, remember to tag me when replaying, so I'll get a notification.

Comment: @Marti sure if I do not find the final solution I will share the file with you. And on your question `google.script.run.indiaddrecord` this is been called twice. but my simple question is that `google.script.run.` is under function `dostuffLeavenew` which is called by pressing the <button> in html how can this be called twice this function `dostuffLeavenew` is independent how can it be called twice?

Comment: @Captain_D If the function is called twice, what I would so is change the `onclick` to `test123` and see what happens. Do not change the name anywhere else (yet).

Comment: @Martí ok you mean `test123="dostuffLeavenew()"` like this?

Comment: @Captain_D I meant the other way around. Sorry, it wasn't very clear. Actually, could you change your submit button to `<a class="btn" onclick="test123()" ondblclick="alert('dbclick')">Submit</a>`? It can tell us a lot depending on the behavior.

Comment: @Martí ok no alert shown not even once. but then I removed `var singleModalElem = document.getElementById('modal1');
            var instance = M.Modal.getInstance(singleModalElem);
            instance.open();` this part and it fired only once but again no alert. This part of code refresh my page and and I believe refreshing is causing the script to run twice. but I need to refresh page too so I can't just disable this part of code.

Comment: @Captain_D As you probably know, if you only wanted to close the modal you can change the `href="#!"` on the close button. If you are doing more work, maybe the error is somewhere else. Is there a chance to give access to an anonymous and reduced version of your code? That is, a version without personal and private information (this is public). It would be perfect if you cold remove all the code that doesn't affect this behavior.